# Grape entities conditional expose if field is NOT nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape

In a grape-entity, I want to show a field only if present (not nil?) with no luck.

I'm trying this code but doesn't work as expected at all, but hiding the field always.

```
expose :winner, :using => PlayerEntity, :unless => { :winner => nil }
```

I think the code itself explains what I really need but, as I say, I'm not getting the expected result.

Any clue?

Answer (score 11):

Ok, checking grape-entity's code I figured out you need to pass this block as a Ruby Proc.
This code will work as expected:

```
expose :winner, :using => PlayerEntity, :unless => Proc.new {|g| g.winner.nil?}
```

Hope it helps someone.
Cheers

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-entity#expose-nil

Grape Entity now provides `expose_nil` option, so this should do the trick:

```
expose :winner, :using => PlayerEntity, expose_nil: false
```